# Cannot run execve on files that are blocked to /usr/libexec/amfid

Tags: authorization, kernel-extension, xnu

I wanted to use Kauth in order to block some files from being executed by other processes except mine. However, it seems like even I cannot run the process since I also block the file from amfid (The mobile file integrity daemon, funny it's also existed in macOS).

Here's the following path to the process `/usr/libexec/amfid`

does my assumption right ? does any mach-o file need to be accessed by amfid for inspection prior to execution ?